# Least common multiple of $10!18!$ and $12!17!$ in the form $\cfrac{a!b!}{c!} $ where a,b are two-digits numbers and c one-digit number.

Tags: number-theory

If the least common multiple of $10!18!$ and $12!17!$ is expressed in the form of $\cfrac{a!b!}{c!}$,where $a$ and $b$ are two-digits numbers  and $c$ is one-digits number,find $abc$.

Can you guys give me some hint ?

Comment: In your title, there is no factorial on the $17$. Is that a typo?

Comment: yes,sorry I am editing.

Comment: Hint: compute $\frac{18!12!}{10!18!}$ and $\frac{18!12!}{12!17!}$

Comment: Well the since those are both integers the least common multiple must divide $18!12!$ and if you divide by the greatest common divisor of those two numbers you will find the least common multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$10!\cdot18!=10!\cdot17!\cdot6\cdot3$$

and $$12!\cdot17!=10!\cdot17!\cdot 6\cdot 22.$$

Thus considering the LCM of $3$ and $22$, we get that

$$\text{LCM}(10!\cdot18!,12!\cdot17!)=10!\cdot17!\cdot 6\cdot 22\cdot3.$$
This can be rewritten as 
$$
10!\cdot17!\cdot 6\cdot 22=10!\cdot17!\cdot11\cdot2\cdot6\cdot3=12!\cdot17!\cdot3=\frac{12!\cdot17!\cdot3\cdot6}{6}=\frac{12!18!}{3!}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$10!18!=10!17!\times 18=10!17!\times 6 \times 3$$
$$12!17!=10!17!\times 12\times11=10!17!\times 6 \times22$$
$$\text{G.C.D}=10!17!\times6=\frac{10!18!\times3}{18}=\frac{10!18!}{3!}$$

Comment: This is wrong, $10!\cdot17!\cdot6$ is not divisible by either of the two numbers in consideration here and thus cannot be the LCM...

Comment: Sorry I thought it was G.C.D.